# Can a WCF service.config file be changed on the fly?

Tags: wcf

Its a newbie question, and I have just been learning WCF. 
Can we change the service.config file of a WCF service on the fly without restarting the App Pool or doing the deployment?

Regards,
Bhavik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, IIS will automatically detect the change to the config file and recycle the app pool automatically for you.  So in a sense, the app pool does have to be recycled, but it handles it for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're hosting your services in IIS and you change the web.config file, the app pool will automatically recycle.